# Replace %22 by &quot; with mod_rewrite in query string

Tags: mod-rewrite

Have tried a lot of RewriteRule, even the previous suggested posts. Unfortunately, none works. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all `%22` with `&quot;` in the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\%22(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&quot;%2 [L,R]
```

However, the `&` is used to separate query string parameters, so if you start with:

```
?abc=%22def%22&xyz=123
```

It'll change it to:

```
?abc=&quot;def&quot;&xyz=123
```

which means the parameters will be

abc=
   quot;def
   quot;
   xyz=123

You probably want to escape the `&` so that doesn't happen:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\%22(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1\%26quot;%2 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have tried this before, but this only replace the last %22. As per your example this will change to abc= %22 def quot; xyz=123

Comment: @KarmakarA After the first replace, the redirect causes the rules to execute *again*, thus replacing the other.